# PlayAudit function call is closing the browser/page automatically after first Lighthouse analysis

Tags: ui-automation, playwright, lighthouse, playwright-test, playwright-lighthouse

We are trying to perform Lighthouse analysis on a web application by using Playwright-lighthouse library as a utility by calling it in multiple stages within a single test.

Sample:

`Before all {`
`browser initiation }`

`test {`

`goto(url);`
`await playaudit{}`
`locator().click();`
`await playaudit{}`

`};`

Problem is once the URL is opened and playaudit() function is called, the browser is automatically closing leading to which the locator().click() is throwing **Error: locator.click: Target page, context or browser has been closed error.**

I'm currently using downgraded version of lightHouse & playwright-lighthouse due to existing import issue in latest versions.
**"@playwright/test": "^1.35.1",
"lighthouse": "^9.6.8",
"playwright-lighthouse": "^2.2.2"**,

Can PlayAudit() be called multiple times within a single test? If not possible by design, are there any workarounds possible ?

Thanks!

Expectation: PlayAudit() function can be called multiple times within a single Playwright test without browser/page getting closed.